# MySQL varchar index storage

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, enums

I have an application built using the Laravel framework. One of its features is the ability to create polymorphic relationships between tables. It does this by storing the ID of the related table and the fully qualified class name of the related table's model. As you can imagine, some of the entries can be quite long depending on the namespaces and class name of the model.

In my scenario, I have 4 tables. Base table `A` which is polymorphic. Tables `B`, `C`, and `D` which are not.

The class names for the non polymorphic table models like this:

```
LongNamespace\SubNamespace\Something\B
LongNamespace\SubNamespace\Something\C
LongNamespace\SubNamespace\Something\D
```

Results from table `A` would look like:

```
id | relation_id | relation_type
--------------------------------
1  | 1           | LongNamespace\SubNamespace\Something\B
2  | 2           | LongNamespace\SubNamespace\Something\C
3  | 5           | LongNamespace\SubNamespace\Something\D
4  | 12          | LongNamespace\SubNamespace\Something\D
5  | 3           | LongNamespace\SubNamespace\Something\B
6  | 6           | LongNamespace\SubNamespace\Something\C

... etc (around 50,000 rows) ...
```

With 38 bytes per record added, most of which is repeated data, my question is, would adding an index onto the `relation_type` column store every individual `relation_type` record individually in memory (which I assume is what happens with indexes) or will it group them up like an ENUM so the total storage would be the 3 unique entries in `relation_type` which are then internally associated by a hash table of some sort, ergo saving n*38 bytes worth of space.

Answer (score 0):

An index contains all the text of all the indexed columns, plus (in the case of InnoDB) all the text of all the `PRIMARY KEY` columns.  So, 38*n bytes are 'wasted'.

If you declared `relation_type` to be

```
ENUM(`LongNamespace\SubNamespace\Something\B`,
     `LongNamespace\SubNamespace\Something\C`,
     `LongNamespace\SubNamespace\Something\D`,
     ...)
```

then it would take only 1 or 2 bytes, yet act very much like those 39-byte strings.

There is, of course, maintenance problems when you add another Table, etc.

On the other hand, 38*50K = ~2MB is "small", and not really a big deal.

No, an index is not kept in RAM.  It is, however, "cached" in RAM, block by block.  So if the index (or table) were really big, there would be extra I/O due to things not staying in cache (RAM).  But it would still "work", albeit slowly.